# PHP on IIS doesn't load sqlsrv extension

Tags: php, sql-server, iis, sqlsrv

I'm trying to put together a page that can submit data from a form to an MSSQL database via PHP. I've got PHP installed successfully (`phpinfo()` runs fine even on a remote computer) but it will not load the [sqlsrv extension](http://sqlsrvphp.codeplex.com/). I know that I'm editing the right `php.ini` file because I have another extension added (wincache) and it is loading fine, confirmed with both `phpinfo()` and `get_loaded_extensions()`.

The logs aren't telling me anything. PHP Manager on IIS is telling me that the sqlsrv extension files are enabled. I've restarted the website, the server, and the computer, and nothing's working.

I'm using PHP 7.1.1 on a Windows 7 Ultimate machine. It's running in x64 mode, Non-Thread Safe. I've made sure that the extension files I enabled are the x64, non-thread-safe ones. I don't know what else to check or what more info I need to provide.

**EDIT:** I ran `php-cgi.exe` as [this page](https://forums.iis.net/t/1162267.aspx) suggested, and it came out with the error mesages:

```
[31-Mar-2017 22:38:12 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files\iis express\PHP\v7.1\ext\php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
[31-Mar-2017 22:38:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files\iis express\PHP\v7.1\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
```

Does this mean that the problem is in the extension DLLs themselves? How would I even go about fixing that?

**EDIT 2:** ImClarky nailed the problem in that I was apparently using a way outdated version of the extension. I've got it working, but now my authentication is failing for reasons I don't understand:

```
function connect_sql() {
    /* Specify server and connection attributes */
    $serverName = "(local)";

    /* Get UID and PWD from app-specific files */
    $uid = file_get_contents("C:\AppData\uid.txt");
    $pwd = file_get_contents("C:\AppData\pwd.txt");
    $connectionInfo = array("UID" => $uid,
                            "PWD" => $pwd,
                            "Database" => "database_name");

    /* Connect using SQL Server Auth */
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
    if ($conn === false)
    {
        echo "Unable to connect.</br>";
        //die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        die(print_errors());
    }
    else {
        echo "Connection Successful";
    }

    /* Free connection resources */
    sqlsrv_close($conn);
}
```

I've double checked that I am using the correct username and password, and I even went in and created an entirely new login using the exact UID and password I'm trying. I still get the following error message every time:

```
Unable to connect.

SQLSTATE: 28000
code: 18456
message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'username'.

SQLSTATE: 28000
code: 18456
message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'username'.
```

Comment: What version of sqlsrv are you running? The one from codeplex is *old*... [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql) is now the place for the latest versions.

Comment: In addition to the previous comment, if you need a new version, make sure you download version 4.1.3 or above. Previous versions don't have support for PHP 7.1.

Comment: @ImClarky That seemed to do the trick, but now I'm getting authentication errors. I feel like an idiot for getting stuck on those errors, but I've made sure that I've got the correct username and password in the connection script. I'm using the example from [the MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296182(v=sql.105).aspx). I'll edit my question with my script and error message.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add .dll file for extension folder used by php.ini

Also chose correct driver of SQLSRv matched your running PHP

SQLSRv [sqlsrv from official microsoft page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098)